# How can a stack trace be used to determine the cause of a crash?

Tags: c++, crash, stack, interpreter, root-framework

I understand the "big idea" behind stack traces, but how would one actually go about using a stack trace to determine the cause of a crash? For example, I'm coding a c++ macro, and my interpreter spits out the following stack trace:

```
>  *** Break *** illegal instruction
> 
> 
> 
> =========================================================== There was a crash. This is the entire stack trace of all threads:
> ===========================================================
> #0  0x00007fb64ef29bbc in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #1  0x00007fb64eea7ea2 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #2  0x00007fb64ffb3d84 in TUnixSystem::StackTrace (this=0x98e960) at /cvmfs/myusername/trunk/centos7/source/root-6.16.00/core/unix/src/TUnixSystem.cxx:2413
> #3  0x00007fb64ffb64bc in TUnixSystem::DispatchSignals (this=0x98e960, sig=kSigIllegalInstruction) at
> /cvmfs/myusername/trunk/centos7/source/root-6.16.00/core/unix/src/TUnixSystem.cxx:3644
> #4  <signal handler called>
> #5  0x00007fb65057f54a in ?? ()
> #6  0x000000000146e4ec in ?? ()
> #7  0x000000000028dc9d in ?? ()
> #8  0x0028dcf80146e51c in ?? ()
> #9  0x00007ffd08a37890 in ?? ()
> #10 0x0000000000051b93 in ?? ()
> #11 0x000000000000a372 in ?? ()
> #12 0x0000a3e900051c01 in ?? ()
> #13 0x000000000000146e in ?? ()
> #14 0x00007ffd08a3788f in ?? ()
> #15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> ===========================================================
> 
> 
> The lines below might hint at the cause of the crash. You may get help
> by asking at the ROOT forum http://root.cern.ch/forum Only if you are
> really convinced it is a bug in ROOT then please submit a report at
> http://root.cern.ch/bugs Please post the ENTIRE stack trace from above
> as an attachment in addition to anything else that might help us
> fixing this issue.
> ===========================================================
> #5  0x00007fb65057f54a in ?? ()
> #6  0x000000000146e4ec in ?? ()
> #7  0x000000000028dc9d in ?? ()
> #8  0x0028dcf80146e51c in ?? ()
> #9  0x00007ffd08a37890 in ?? ()
> #10 0x0000000000051b93 in ?? ()
> #11 0x000000000000a372 in ?? ()
> #12 0x0000a3e900051c01 in ?? ()
> #13 0x000000000000146e in ?? ()
> #14 0x00007ffd08a3788f in ?? ()
> #15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> ===========================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the stack trace is to see who was calling who at the moment of the crash. So you can check the function producing the fault and see how it was called.
What you are seeing in your example are the address of your functions, of course if the stack is corrupted somehow you could find invalid addresses as well.
To see more useful information you should compile your code with debugging information, that way you will not only see the address but the name of the function too.
In gcc for example you enable debugging information with '-g', ie:

```
gcc -g test.c -o test
```

Here is an example of the 'test.c' faulty code:

```
void foo()
{
    int a=1/0;
}
void foo1()
{
    foo();
}
void foo2()
{
    foo1();
}
void foo3()
{
    foo2();
}

int main()
{
    foo3();
};
```

this is the backtrace it produces (running in gdb, info is available because I used -g flag for the compilation)

```
#0  0x0000000000401101 in foo () at test.c:3
#1  0x0000000000401117 in foo1 () at test.c:7
#2  0x0000000000401128 in foo2 () at test.c:11
#3  0x0000000000401139 in foo3 () at test.c:15
#4  0x000000000040114a in main () at test.c:20
```

Comment: yes, compile the program with debugging information (-g)

Comment: if you're running your code as what in the root world is called a macro (`root myfile.C` or in the root prompt `.L myfile.C` or `.x myfile.C`), an option is to load the macro compiled `root myfile.C+`/`.L myfile.C+`/`.x myfile.C+` and then you can add debug information by appending a `g` `root myfile.C+g`/`.L myfile.C+g`/`.x myfile.C+g`.